# Problems running SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I can't get SoapUI running. I followed [these](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui) instructions. When I try to do `mvn clean install` on soapui subproject I get these errors:

```
PS D:\soapui\soapui> mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model   for com.smartbear.soapui:soapui:jar:5.2.0-SN
APSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)'  must be unique: org.sonatype.install4j:i4jrunti
me:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 5.1.14 @ line 559, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they  threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support  building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------- ---
[INFO] Building SoapUI 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime:jar:5.1.14 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.293s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 03 10:48:13 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project soapui: Could not resolve  dependencies for project com.smartbear.soapui:soapui
:jar:5.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find   org.sonatype.install4j:i4jruntime:jar:5.1.14 in   http://www.soapui.org/repository/ma
 ven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted  until the update interval of smartbear-swede
 n-repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e  switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please   read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]  http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Also, I have lots of errors, after importing of project into Eclipse.
Some of them are:

```
Project 'soapui-maven-plugin' is missing required Java project: 'soapui- core-DEV'
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library  

'C:\Users\mismas\.m2\repository\com\smartbear\soapui\soapui\5.2.0- SNAPSHOT\soapui-5.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  soapui-maven-plugin


Unbound classpath variable: 'MAVEN_REPO/activation/jars/activation-1.1.jar' in project 'soapui-maven-plugin'    soapui-maven-plugin     Build path  Build Path Problem

Missing artifact gnu.cajo:cajo:jar:1.142   
Missing artifact org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (execution: default-descriptor, phase: generate-resources) pom.xml /soapui-maven-plugin
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3:xmlbeans (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)   pom.xml /soapui
```

Please help, I would really like to use SoapUI for testing of RESTful webservice.
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
mismas

Comment: If you want to just get it running and start testing, why not just download the binary, why build it from source?

Comment: can you provide your pom.xml and also output of mvn dependency:tree of your project

Answer (score 0):

In the file soapui/pom.xml have lines duplicated:
[Duplicate dependency pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8h4i.jpg)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.install4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>i4jruntime</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

You have this error in the maven execution:

> [WARNING]
>   'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)'  must
>   be unique: org.sonatype.install4j:i4jrunti me:jar -> duplicate
>   declaration of version 5.1.14 @ line 559, column 21

you delete this lines and you execute `mvn clean install`